# Populate Textarea - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textarea

My requirement is to populate a textarea based on condition.

- I retrieve signature from db.
- If signature exists populate the textarea with the value.
- If there is no signature, then textarea should contain :
- Enter signature and on clicking  inside the text area, 
  the pre populated tetxt should disappear.
- If the user does not enter any text and clicks outside the area, 
  the pre populated text should come back in the textarea.

My Code is not complete but as a start :

```
<textarea name="signature" 
    style="width:95%" 
    rows="10" 
    onclick="document.mailForm.signature.value='';">
 <c:choose>
  <c:when test="${signature} == '' ">
      <c:out value="${signaturePrefix}" />
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
     <c:out value="${signature}" />
  </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
</textarea>
```

Thanks.

Comment: the concept of StackOverflow is **not**: deliver code based on requirements. please read the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq ;)

Comment: So, what have you tried? What went wrong? Have you come across the [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute), yet?

Comment: An unconditional `onclick="document.mailForm.signature.value='';"` is a great way to annoy people.

Answer (score 0):

For DB part you should paste your code/logic written so far. For text appear/dispaear you can use some jQuery Watermark Plugin:

- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/
- http://remysharp.com/2007/01/25/jquery-tutorial-text-box-hints/  ([Demo](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/input_hint.html))

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. The issue I am having is, first, clicking in the textarea clears the signature that has been populated from the db.I dnt know how to give a condition for it to do this only when the pre populated text is in there. Secondly, I dont know how to get back the pre populated text into the text area once you click  out of it.

Comment: @Viidhya: Therefore I asked you to use a jQuery plugin to save your time. For Example, see this [Demo](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/input_hint.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a click event execute only if the "value" is the empty string. Then, at the end of the handler function, remove the event so that the user doesn't lose all their inputted text.

```
function changeContent(element,type){
    element.innerHTML="";
    element.removeEventListener(type,changeContent,false);
}

<textarea name="signature" style="width:95%" rows="10" 
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${signature} == '' ">
      onclick="contentChange(this,'click');">
      <c:out value="${signaturePrefix}" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      ">
      <c:out value="${signature}" />
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
</textarea>
```

This doesn't work in IE because it uses `detachEvent`. I would recommend using a framework to make this approach corss-browser with the least amount of hair pulling.